# gradient descent for linear regression in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to implement linear regression by gradient descent method in python.
There is a error in my results

**This is a method to get feature spaces**

```
def quadratic (arg_row) :
    poly_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arg_row)):
        poly_arr.append([float(arg_row[i][0])])
        poly_arr[i].append(float(arg_row[i][1]))
        poly_arr[i].append(float(arg_row[i][3]))
        poly_arr[i].append(float(arg_row[i][0])**2)
        poly_arr[i].append(float(arg_row[i][1])**2)
        poly_arr[i].append(float(arg_row[i][1])*float(arg_row[i][0]))

    return poly_arr
```

I am just doing it for a quadratic space

**This is my method to calculate the  gradient descent**

```
def descent(features,train) :
    m_val_avg = []
    m_val_arr = []
    m_val_avg_arr = []
    weights =[]
    rate = 0.001 
    precision = 0.000001 
    previous_step_size = 1 
    max_iters = 1000
    iters = 0 
    for i in range(len(features[0])) :   #weights initalization
        weights.append(1)
    print(weights)
    while iters < max_iters :
          m_val_avg_arr = []
          my_new_list = []   
          current_weights = list(weights)
          error_result = error_cal(features,current_weights,train)
          square_errored = square_error(features,current_weights,train)
          #print(error_result)
          for j in range(len(features[0])) :
              for i in range(len(features)):
                  m_val = error_result[i]*(-features[i][j])
                  m_val_arr.append(m_val)
              m_val_avg = sum(m_val_arr)/len(m_val_arr)
              m_val = []
              m_val_avg_arr.append(m_val_avg)
          #print(m_val_avg_arr)   
          for i in range(len(features[0])):
              my_new_list = np.array(m_val_avg_arr)
              my_new_list = my_new_list*rate
              #print(my_new_list)
              m_grad = current_weights[i]-my_new_list[i]

              weights[i] = m_grad

          iters = iters+1
          print(iters)
          print(square_errored)
```

**This is my method to calculate improved error difference for every iteration**

```
def error_cal(features, weights, train) :
    arr_actcal = []
    diff_cal_result =[]
    for j in range(len(features)) :
        for i in range(len(features[0])) :
            act_cal = features[j][i]*weights[i]
            arr_actcal.append(act_cal)  
        diff_cal = ((train[j][2])-sum(arr_actcal))
        diff_cal_result.append(diff_cal)
        arr_actcal =[]

    return diff_cal_result
```

**This is my method to calculate the squared errors for each iteration.**

```
def square_error (features, weights, train) : 
    arr_actcal_squ = []
    diff_cal_result_squ =[]  
    for j in range(len(features)) :
        for i in range(len(features[0])) :
            act_cal_squ = features[j][i]*weights[i]
            arr_actcal_squ.append(act_cal_squ)  
        diff_cal_squ = ((train[j][2])-sum(arr_actcal_squ))
        diff_cal_result_squ.append(diff_cal_squ)
        new_square_error = np.array(diff_cal_result_squ)**2
        new_square_error_avg = sum(new_square_error/len(new_square_error))
        arr_actcal_squ =[]


    return new_square_error_avg
```

I am doing gradient descent for 1000 times. And at each iteration I am improving my error calculation.
From that result I am calculating the mean squared error for each iteration. 
Ideally the squared error should go on decreasing but for me the error is increasing and then decreasing. I don't know where I am going wrong in my code.

**This is the data for which I am calculating linear regression**

```
6.4432,9.6309,50.9155,1
3.7861,5.4681,29.9852,1
8.1158,5.2114,42.9626,1
5.3283,2.3159,24.7445,1
3.5073,4.8890,27.3704,1
9.3900,6.2406,51.1350,1
8.7594,6.7914,50.5774,1
5.5016,3.9552,30.5206,1
6.2248,3.6744,31.7380,1
5.8704,9.8798,49.6374,1
2.0774,0.3774,10.0634,1
3.0125,8.8517,38.0517,1
4.7092,9.1329,43.5320,1
2.3049,7.9618,33.2198,1
8.4431,0.9871,31.1220,1
1.9476,2.6187,16.2934,1
2.2592,3.3536,19.3899,1
1.7071,6.7973,28.4807,1
2.2766,1.3655,13.6945,1
4.3570,7.2123,36.9220,1
3.1110,1.0676,14.9160,1
9.2338,6.5376,51.2371,1
4.3021,4.9417,29.8112,1
1.8482,7.7905,32.0336,1
9.0488,7.1504,52.5188,1
9.7975,9.0372,61.6658,1
4.3887,8.9092,42.2733,1
1.1112,3.3416,16.5052,1
2.5806,6.9875,31.3369,1
4.0872,1.9781,19.9475,1
5.9490,0.3054,20.4239,1
2.6221,7.4407,32.6062,1
6.0284,5.0002,35.1676,1
7.1122,4.7992,38.2211,1
2.2175,9.0472,36.4109,1
1.1742,6.0987,25.0108,1
2.9668,6.1767,29.8861,1
3.1878,8.5944,37.9213,1
4.2417,8.0549,38.8327,1
5.0786,5.7672,34.4707,1
```

**This is my driver program**

```
#driver
result_fea = quadratic(data_row_str)
result = descent(result_fea,data_row_str) 
# print("-----------------------------------")
print(result)
```

I know there is lot of math involved here. I can give all the formula's that I am using ,if something doesn't make sense. Thank You In advance

Comment: My learning rate is really small. But I did try it with smaller numbers